# Adding multiple sources to geometric network using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geometric-network, rivers

I am using ArcMap.

I would like to identify all points that are on a river within 10km downstream of a starting point. I have multiple starting points and would like to do this from each of them.

I would like to add multiple sources, from one input file of around 2500 points, to a geometric network.

Do they need to be added as sources? If so, how?

Are there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: If have no idea what you mean by "do they need to be added as sources". Which software are you working with? Have you a workflow? Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk/Online-Manual/Findsitesdownstreamofasite.html) can find downstream sites and network does not need to be a geometric network. It can also search upstream and identify sources, check out the help file.

Comment: Hi Erik, this would be in ESRI ArcMap using a geometric network. I have also tried Trace in ESRI ArcPro. I have tried manually adding a start point which works but I have 2500 of them so was hoping to be able to add more than one at a time.